# Displaying Multiple Images on a Single Google Glass Live Card

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm creating a live card app that recieves PNGs from a php script running on my server in response to a request from scanning QR codes. At the moment, I simply replace the image on my Live card with the PNG I recieve from the server, but I would like to recieve and display multiple images from the server with each request.

Is there an approved way to show multiple images on a live card? I was thinking there may be a possiblity of generating a menu full of images that simply closed itself when clicked, but it seems like there might be a better alternative.

This is my code at the moment:

### Current Code

```
import com.google.android.glass.timeline.LiveCard;
import com.google.android.glass.timeline.LiveCard.PublishMode;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class iotSplashScreen extends Service {

    private static final String LIVE_CARD_TAG = "iotSplashScreen";
    private LiveCard mLiveCard;
    private RemoteViews mLiveCardView;

    public class iotBinder extends Binder {
        public void changeImage(String change) {
            try {
                byte[] bob = Base64.decode(change, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bob, 0, bob.length);
                if(bitmap != null) {
                    mLiveCardView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image_view_id, bitmap);
                    mLiveCard.setViews(mLiveCardView);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Daaang, dat bitmap was null doe");
                }
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Base64 had an issues: " + e);
                System.out.println(change);
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Null Pointer: " + e);
            }
        }
    }

    private final iotBinder mBinder = new iotBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (mLiveCard == null) {
            mLiveCard = new LiveCard(this, LIVE_CARD_TAG);

            mLiveCardView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.iot_splash_screen);
            mLiveCard.setViews(mLiveCardView);

            // Display the options menu when the live card is tapped.
            Intent menuIntent = new Intent(this, LiveCardMenuActivity.class);
            mLiveCard.setAction(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, menuIntent, 0));
            mLiveCard.publish(PublishMode.REVEAL);
        } else {
            mLiveCard.navigate();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mLiveCard != null && mLiveCard.isPublished()) {
            mLiveCard.unpublish();
            mLiveCard = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is really your `mLiveCard` class?

Comment: Added the entire file for clarity. The mLiveCard is just my Current Live Card that's produced from the main Glass menu.

Comment: And what your `iot_splash_screen` layout looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add more ImageViews, either in your layout file (iot_splash_screen) or programmatically.

With the resource IDs of your ImageViews, you can call [setImageViewResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) on each one.

Make sure that you are setting these images before calling `setViews` on your Live Card.

Comment: Considering this is a live card, how would this be displayed to the user? As a menu coming out of the live card? Or would it add several live cards to the timeline? Or would it show them all on the same card? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: It would show all images (ImageViews set in the layout file) on the same live card.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks!
My goal for this project is to have each PNG take up it's own, full screen though. Is there a way to do that in a live card, instead of them having to share space (like in a popup menu)? Or should I switch card types at this point?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I see. You could probably add actions to the menu to change the image on the Live Card (like "Next image" or "Previous image"). However, using [CardScroller](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/card-scroller) might be better.

Comment: Hey, Sorry it's been over a month, I had to focus on other parts of the Project. Your recommendation of CardScroller was spot on. I'm gonna mark this whole thread as correct. Thank you for your help!